# How would I start to decode this? Asking for help from a friend (Alien Hominid Invasion)

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, file-format, game-hacking, exe

I have literally no idea how to start to decode this kind of a file, but I really want these fonts and a decoder would be huge for the community, so any help would be great. Linked below is a google drive folder with the launcher and game exe files and the archive. Are there apps that help with the process of decoding?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jQa36d3wCQyAdjLwjfCSMYeyQrwqADer?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to reverse engineering stack overflow. No one would download unknown files, unless u provide some background information and source. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generic answer:

When you want to unpack/decrypt files like this, the best idea is always to reverse the program that is able to read the file correctly. I think that in Windows operating system the most popular combo for reading files is probably `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` api calls. If you track every operation performed on the buffer filled using `ReadFile` call, you can reconstruct the algorithm that is used to make sense of the bytes stored in the file. You can do it using any debugger like `x64dbg`, `windbg` etc.

Answer to your case:

Sometimes it is worth to check if particular format was already reversed by someone. There is a community around a program called [QuickBMS](https://aluigi.altervista.org/quickbms.htm) that targets unpacking game files. If you open your `fonts.pak` using hex editor, you can notice the very first bytes equal to `PKTB`. If you search for a script that can unpack `PKTB` files on the website, there is one result for a game called [Pit People](https://aluigi.altervista.org/bms/pit_people.bms). The game is created by the same manufacturer as your Alien Hominid Invasion.

Quick look on the script: `fonts.pak` contains 5 files (2 png, 2 bmf(?) and 1 txt). Unfortunately, this quick bms script can't read encrypted filenames (that are probably stored at the very end of `fonts.pak`, (but you can reverse it by yourself of course) what is funnier the header of the file is xored via key which is scrambled form of string `securitythroughobscurity`

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about RE-ing those .EXE files, then take a look into IDA.

IDA
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/

There are other applications that work some what, such as Ollydbg